# Problem with Django and MySQL. NotSupportedError( django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: MariaDB 10.3 or later is required (found 5.5.65)

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework, mariadb

I'm using Django for a project with MySQL. I created a virtual environment and installed mysqlclient to connect to the database. But when I try to start the server I get this error.
[image]

Here's is my version of MariaDB, I installed using Homebrew.
[image]
[image]

And finally the version of mysqlclient in my virtual environment:
[image]

Comment: You have a MariaDB-10.8.3 client installed to a MySQL-8.0.30 server, and your application found 5.5.65 somewhere else? Are you talking a python or container or vm as the "virtual environment"?

Comment: Please don't upload images! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error today when i was hosting my Django app on Heroku. it turned out to be the version of Mysql on  `CLEARDB DATABASE` i added was `5.6.50`. so i changed my add-on Mysql to JawsDB MySQL  and everything worked perfectly. hope it helps